# How to hide an application icon from a device's menu?

Tags: java, android

I have the following question - I need that my user can't see my application's icon on his menu, only in his list of programms installed. Is it possible?

Comment: This really isn't good practice. I certainly wouldn't be happy with an app which didn't provide a launcher of some sort. What are you trying to achieve and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`

remove the following line (which tells android to show the app in the launcher):

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`